# Explanation of this condition in binary tree

Tags: c++

I found a program online that traverses a binary tree in level order.  The code below passes and produces the desired output:

```
class Solution {
public:

    std::vector< vector< int >> res;

    void buildVec(TreeNode* root, int level) {
        if(root==NULL)
            return;
        if(res.size()==level)
            res.push_back(vector< int >());

        res[level].push_back(root->val);
        buildVec(root->left, level+1);
        buildVec(root->right, level+1);
    }

    vector<vector<int>> levelOrder(TreeNode* root) {
        res.clear();
        buildVec(root, 0);
        return res;
    }
};
```

What I don't understand is the statement: `if(res.size()==level)`.  What exactly does this statement achieve?  When the level is 2, there can be (at max) 4 elements (since levels start with 0), which is greater than the value of label (2).  So, how does this statement work?

Edit:  So, if the input is:

```
   3
 /  \
9   20
   /  \
  15   7
```

then the output returned would be

```
[
   [3],
   [9,20],
   [15,7],
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is there is to avoid having the second recursive call to `buildVec` add another level-vector to the end of the result vector, even though the first call already added one for this particular level.

It is easiest to figure out what is going on by doing an example run on your example tree without 15 and 7.

The first thing `levelOrder` does is empty the `res` vector. Then it calls `buildVec(root, 0)`. In there `root` isn't equal to `NULL`, but it holds `res.size() = 0 = level`, so an empty vector gets appended to `res`, thus `res = [[]]`. In the next step the value of the current node is pushed into the newly appended vector. So `res = [[3]]`.

Then `buildVec(root->left, 1)` is called. There, again `root` isn't NULL but `res.size() = 1 = level`, so another empty vector is appended to `res`,  therefore `res = [[3], []]`. We insert the value 9 into `res[1]`, so  now `res = [[3], [9]]`.

When calling `buildVec(root->left, 2)` and `buildVec(root->right, 2)` nothing happens because both children don't exist, i.e. in these calls `root == NULL` returns true.

So we continue with the call `buildVec(root->right, 1)`. Here, for the first time, `res.size() = 2 != 1 = level`. So we don't append a new vector. Then we insert the value `20` into `res[1]`. So `res = [[3], [9, 20]]`.

Were the check `res.size() == level` not there, we would've appended a new empty vector at the end, so the result would've been `res = [[3], [9, 20], []]` instead.

But as it turns out, the check is incorrect. If you flip the tree to

```
     3
   /   \
  20    9
 / \
15  7
```

it will return `[[3], [20, 9], [15, 7], []]`. 
The correct check is `res.size() <= level`.

Comment: @Ramesh Please also upvote the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: @Ramesh, Oh sorry, didn't remember you need a certain amount of reputation to upvode. Nevermind then.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(res.size()==level)
    res.push_back(vector< int >());
```

This statement is just to add another vector into the `res` for a new level.

```
  3
 /  \
9   20
   /  \
  15   7
```

Let's take for node `15` the level will be `2`.

the value of `res` will be `[[3], [9, 20]]` and `res.size() == 2`, condition will be true, so it will create a new vector for new level and insert the node `15` in it, again for node `7` the condition will be false since the `res.size()` will become `3` so the node will be inserted in the `res[level]` vector without creating the new vector.